# How to select the finest granularity of string items in a list

Tags: python, list

I hava a list of strings:

> [u'This', u'the third largest earthquake in recorded history', u'the
>   third largest earthquake', u'recorded history', u'massive tsunamis ,
>   which caused widespread devastation when they hit land , leaving an
>   estimated 230,000 people dead in countries around the Bay of Bengal
>   and the Indian Ocean', u'massive tsunamis', u'widespread devastation',
>   u'they', u'land', u'an estimated 230,000 people dead in countries
>   around the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'an estimated 230,000
>   people', u'countries around the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean',
>   u'countries', u'the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'the Bay',
>   u'Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'Bengal', u'the Indian Ocean']

You can see that, some elements contain other elements, like:

> u'the third largest earthquake in recorded history'

Contains:

> u'the third largest earthquake'
>
> u'recorded history'

How can I only select the finest granularity elements like  `u'recorded history'` and discard the remaining elements?

Comment: define what you mean by finest granularity ? It sounds like you are trying to do lexical analysis (i.e. understanding the meaning of the words, and  maybe even the phrases that contain those words).

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, I only want to select the smallest entity which doesn't contain other entity.

Comment: define entity - all that python will see are strings & characters. You can make python 'see' words, but spliting on whitespace or punctuation, but even that will take a small amount of code. Why is u'recorded history' the smallest entity, and why isn't u'history' or event 'o' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this does what you are asking for:

```
In [14]: allstrings = [u'This', u'the third largest earthquake in recorded history', u'the third largest earthquake', u'recorded history', u'massive tsunamis , which caused widespread devastation when they hit land , leaving an estimated 230,000 people dead in countries around the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'massive tsunamis', u'widespread devastation', u'they', u'land', u'an estimated 230,000 people dead in countries around the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'an estimated 230,000 people', u'countries around the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'countries', u'the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'the Bay', u'Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'Bengal', u'the Indian Ocean']

In [15]: [s for s in allstrings if not any(t in s for t in allstrings if t != s)]
Out[15]: 
[u'This',
 u'the third largest earthquake',
 u'recorded history',
 u'massive tsunamis',
 u'widespread devastation',
 u'they',
 u'land',
 u'an estimated 230,000 people',
 u'countries',
 u'the Bay',
 u'Bengal',
 u'the Indian Ocean']
```

The list comprehension starts out simple.  It selects the strings from your master list, `allstrings`, that satisfy some condition: `[s for s in allstrings if ....]`

The condition that the string, `s`, must satisfy to be in the final list is:

```
not any(t in s for t in allstrings if t != s)
```

As you can see, this tests whether any other string, `t`, in `allstrings` is in `s`.  If there is no such string `t`, then `s` is included in the final list.

#### Possible Refinement

Is the entity `'the'` contained in the entity `'they'`?  The answer depends on what we mean by entity.  If we decide that the answer is no, then we should make a minor change to the algorithm.  The simplest approach would seem to be padding every string with spaces.  As an example:

```
In [25]: u'the' in u'they'
Out[25]: True

In [26]: u' the ' in u' they '
Out[26]: False
```

To implement this, we add a step which adds spaces, run the entity check, and then remove the surplus spaces:

```
In [30]: allstrings = [u'This', u'the third largest earthquake in recorded history', u'the third largest earthquake', u'recorded history', u'massive tsunamis , which caused widespread devastation when they hit land , leaving an estimated 230,000 people dead in countries around the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'massive tsunamis', u'widespread devastation', u'they', u'land', u'an estimated 230,000 people dead in countries around the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'an estimated 230,000 people', u'countries around the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'countries', u'the Bay of Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'the Bay', u'Bengal and the Indian Ocean', u'Bengal', u'the Indian Ocean']

In [31]: allstr2 = [u' {} '.format(s.strip()) for s in allstrings]

In [32]: [s.strip() for s in allstr2 if not any(t in s for t in allstr2 if t != s)]
Out[32]: 
[u'This',
 u'the third largest earthquake',
 u'recorded history',
 u'massive tsunamis',
 u'widespread devastation',
 u'they',
 u'land',
 u'an estimated 230,000 people',
 u'countries',
 u'the Bay',
 u'Bengal',
 u'the Indian Ocean']
```

As you can see, this refinement makes no difference for the given strings but it might for others.

Comment: I'll take a pray first, before try to understand :)

Comment: `all` is a built-in function, try not to actually use that.

Comment: @John1024 Thank you so much, it all comes down to the logic on how to write that one liner beauty, which I struggled with for days.

Comment: @John1024 Could you tell me where I can learn to write such beautiful code as you? Such as complex list comprehension as you displayed?

Comment: @Sean Thank you for that most kind compliment!  I have no special suggestions: just read and practice.  One can learn a lot just following the stackoverflow questions tagged `python`.